# Unable to pass object inside directive in angularjs?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, restangular

Here is the code for directive

```
module.exports = ()=>{
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    templateUrl: "/components/editor/editor.html",
    scope: {channel: '='},
    controller: "editorCtrl"
  };
};
```

the controller

```
module.exports = ($scope,$rootScope)=>{
  console.log($scope.channel);
};
```

and i am calling the same from template using

```
.container(ng-controller="blogCtrl" ng-init="getOne()")
  h1(ng-bind="blog.title")
  editor(channel="blog")
```

Relevant parts for blogCtrl

```
module.exports = ($scope,$rootScope,api,$routeParams)=>{
  $scope.getOne = ()=>{
    $scope.data = null;
    $scope.error = null;
    var id = $routeParams.blogSlug;
    api.one("blog",id)
      .then((resp)=>{
        $scope.blog = resp.data;
      })
      .catch((err)=>{
        $scope.error = err.message;
      });
  }
};
```

And the codes for api factory is

```
module.exports = ($rootScope,$localStorage,Restangular)=>{
  var helper = {};

  helper.one = (model,id)=>{
    return new Promise((fullfill,reject)=>{
      $rootScope.$broadcast("loaderInit");
      Restangular
        .one(model,id)
        .get()
        .then(fullfill)
        .then(()=>{
          $rootScope.$broadcast("loaderEnd");
        })
        .catch((err)=>{
          $rootScope.$broadcast("loaderEnd");
          reject(err);
        });
    });
  }
  return helper;
}
```

I am not sure why but the channel always comes as undefined. Where am i going wrong ?

Comment: where's `blogCtrl`?

Comment: Let me add that part also .. One second

Comment: @DanielA.White added that. the h1 binding is working so i don't think there is problem fetching the post

Comment: what's api? is taht a $q promise?

Comment: Yeah thats a factory that returns promise... that has relevant part of restangular calls.. Do you need that ?

Comment: might be good to get a [mcve]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/137161/discussion-between-georoot-and-daniel-a-white).